# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is adding chinese characters

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

A string like this: `@"coffee--a";`

After trying to remove `--a`:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"--a" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I got the following result:

```
NSLog(@"%@",str);//coffeeeeᥴ팈㶸
```

The last two characters are duplicated and the rest are strange characters. How to fix that?

Comment: Did you really forget the argument in `NSLog(@"%@")` ? It should be `NSLog(@"%@", str)` ! Also note that the result of the first line is not used in the second line.

Comment: Oh yes, a typo, sorry

Comment: Please copy/paste your *real code*.

Comment: Your example reads `str = [searchString stringByAddingPercent`. Did you mean `str stringByAddingPercent`? If not, you're throwing away the results of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Comment: Edited my post, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: How is the initial string `str` created? What does `NSLog(@"%@", str)` show *before* the transformations?

Comment: `str` is an instance variable, it gets assigned when user press return on keyboard: `textFieldShouldReturn`. before transformation, `str` is reflecting the same string entered in the `UITextField`, in this example: `coffee--a`.